# Change a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm checking a string with this regular expression:`/^[SE]*[\s]*[0-9]{3}[\s\-]*[0-9]{2}$/`. This allows a total of 9 different formats, being: XXXXX, XXX-XX, XXX XX, SEXXXXX, SEXXX-XX, SEXXX XX, SE XXXXX, SE XXX-XX and SE XXX XX (X:s being any number from 0-9). How do I change the format to XXXXX after the check passes for one of the 9 valid formats?

I've read a bunch of other threads about the `string.replace()`-method but I can't seem to make it work. Here's my code so far:

```
        var pcValue = postalCode.value;
        var format = /^[SE]*[\s]*[0-9]{3}[\s\-]*[0-9]{2}$/;

        if (format.test(pcValue) === true) {
            pcValue = pcValue.replace(/\[SE]*[\s]*[\s\-]*$/, /^[0-9]{5}$/);
        }
```

What it gives me is a string with `/^[0-9]{5}$/` instead of the XXXXX format I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var format = /^([SE]*)\s*(\d{3})[\s\-]*(\d\d)$/;
if (format.test(pcValue)) {
    pcValue = pcValue.replace(format, "$2$3");
}
```

Note that if you don't do anything else than replacing if `test` returns true, then you don't have to test at all, just execute the replacement.

Comment: It works but if there is a SE at the beginning it's still there after the replacement. How do i remove it aswell?

Comment: @Lemonmuncher Edited to remove the SE

Answer (score 0):

```
var pcValue = postalCode.value;
var format = /^[SE]*[\s]*[0-9]{3}[\s\-]*[0-9]{2}$/;

if (format.test(pcValue) === true) {
    pcValue = pcValue.replace(/\[SE]*[\s]*[\s\-]*$/, /^[0-9]{5}$/);
}

str.replace(original,replicant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pcValue = postalCode.value;
pcValue = pcValue.replace(/^[SE]*[\s]*([0-9]{3})[\s\-]*([0-9]{2})$/, "$1$2");
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/uLJEm/

Comment: Worked like a charm! Even removed the eventual SE's.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you've marked as accepted also validates these kinds of inputs :

```
"ES 12345"
"SSSSS 123 -  45"
"SESE     123---45"
```

The following regular expression might better fit with your needs :

```
function parse(input) {
    var re = /^(?:SE)?\s?(\d{3})(?:\s|-)?(\d\d)$/;
    return re.test(input) && input.replace(re, '$1$2');
}
```

```js
var input1 = parse('SE 123 45'); // 12345
var input2 = parse('ES 123 45'); // false
input1 || alert('Please fix input #1!');
input2 || alert('Please fix input #2!'); // alert!
```

A little help about `/^(?:SE)?\s?(\d{3})(?:\s|-)?(\d\d)$/` :

```
^...$       string boundaries
(...)       capture match
(?:...)     don't capture match

(?:SE)?     "SE", zero or one time
\s?         a whitespace, zero or one time
(\d{3})     3 digits (captured -> $1)
(?:\s|-)?   a whitespace or a dash, zero or one time
(\d\d)      2 digits (captured -> $2)
```

More on regular expressions : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.